# Exception in thread Thread-1:

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Thread module that will call a function to ssh on a devices

ssh_conenction.py module

```
import paramiko
import os.path
import time
import sys
import re

# ask the user to input the path of the credential file
user_file = input("\n* Enter user file path and name (e.g. D:\\MyFiles\\file.txt): ")
# check if the file is exist or not
if os.path.isfile(user_file):
    print("\n* username and password file is valid :)\n")
    # if not exist then the program will exit
else:
    print("the username/password file is not valid :( Please check it and try again.")
    sys.exit()
# now check if the command file exist or not
command_file = input("\n Enter the command file path (e.g. D:\\MyFiles\\file.txt): ")

if os.path.isfile(command_file):
    print("\n* Command file is valid:)")

else:
    print("\n* command file is not valid please check it and try again.")


def ssh_connection(ip):
    global user_file
    global command_file
    try:
        # we will read the user/pass file and extract the username and password
        selected_user_file = open(user_file, 'r')
        selected_user_file.seek(0)
        # print(selected_user_file.readlines()[0]) admin,python
        # we are reading lines and get a list with each line as an element of that list
        # then we will strip with the delimiter ',' and get the first index and rstrip the \n in case it's exist
        # i was using strip instead of split which will remove the ','
        username = selected_user_file.readlines()[0].split(',')[0].rstrip('\n')
        # you need to start again from the start of the line
        selected_user_file.seek(0)
        password = selected_user_file.readlines()[0].split(',')[1].rstrip('\n')

        # invoke the ssh client class from paramiko
        session = paramiko.SSHClient()
        # the below is used in testing environment that will accept any host key
        # in production it must be RejectPolicy and accepting only the Keys you know
        session.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

        # connect to a device using it's username and password
        session.connect(ip.rstrip(','), username=username, password=password)

        # start an interactive session on the router
        connection = session.invoke_shell()

        # setting the terminal length for entire output - disable pagination
        connection.send("enable\n")
        connection.send("terminal length 0\n")
        time.sleep(1)

        # enter the global configuration mode
        connection.send("\n")
        connection.send("configure terminal\n")
        time.sleep(1)

        # Open command file for reading
        selected_cmd_file = open(command_file, 'r')
        selected_cmd_file.seek(0)

        # writing each line to the device
        for each_line in selected_cmd_file:
            connection.send(each_line + '\n')
            time.sleep(2)

        # closing the user and cmd file
        selected_user_file.close()
        selected_cmd_file.close()

        # checking the command output for any syntax error
        router_output = connection.recv(65535)

        if re.search(b"% Invalid input", router_output):
            print("There was at least one IOS syntax error on device with IP {} :(".format(ip))
        else:
            print("\nDone for device with IP {} :)".format(ip))

        # Test for reading the command output
        print(str(router_output) + "\n")

        # closing the connection
        session.close()

    except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
        print("\nInvalid username or password :( \n* Please check the username/password and try again")
        print("* Closing program...bye ")
```

and the threading module

```
import threading

# creating threads
def create_threads(iplist, function):
    threads = []
    for ip in iplist:
        th = threading.Thread(target=function, args=(ip,))
        # args is a tuple with a single element
        th.start()
        threads.append(th)

    for th in threads:
        th.join()
```

and in the app script i called the thread to ssh on all devices

```
# importing the necessary modules
import sys

from ip_file_valid import ip_file_valid
from ip_addr_valid import ip_addr_valid
from ip_reach import ip_reach
from ssh_connection import ssh_connection
from create_threads import create_threads

# Saving the list of IP addresses in ip.txt to avariable
ip_list = ip_file_valid()

# verifying the validity of each IP address in the list
try:
    ip_addr_valid(ip_list)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("\n\n* Program aborted by user. Exiting...\n")
    sys.exit()

# verifying reachability for each ip in the list
try:
    ip_reach(ip_list)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("\n\n* Program aborted by user.Exiting....\n")
    sys.exit()

# calling threads creation function for one or multiple SSH connections
create_threads(ip_list, ssh_connection)

# End of the program
```

but i am getting this exception

```
* 10.10.10.2 is reachable

* 10.10.10.3 is reachable

* 10.10.10.4 is reachable
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\D\Cloud Learning\Python\R W Device Conf\ssh_connection.py", line 49, in ssh_connection
    session.connect(ip.rstrip(','), username=username, password=password)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 340, in connect
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\D\Cloud Learning\Python\R W Device Conf\ssh_connection.py", line 49, in ssh_connection
    to_try = list(self._families_and_addresses(hostname, port))
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 203, in _families_and_addresses
    session.connect(ip.rstrip(','), username=username, password=password)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 340, in connect
    addrinfos = socket.getaddrinfo(
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 953, in getaddrinfo
    to_try = list(self._families_and_addresses(hostname, port))
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 203, in _families_and_addresses
    addrinfos = socket.getaddrinfo(
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 953, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Done for device with IP 10.10.10.4 :)
b'Last login: Sat Mar  6 13:31:23 2021 from 10.10.10.1\r\r\nenable\r\nterminal length 0\r\nenable\nterminal length 0\nlocalhost>enable\r\nlocalhost#terminal length 0\r\nPagination disabled.\r\nlocalhost#\r\nconfigure terminal\r\nlocalhost#configure terminal\r\nlocalhost(config)#show interfaces loopback 0\r\nLoopback0 is up, line protocol is up (connected)\r\n  Hardware is Loopback\r\n  Internet address is 3.3.3.3/24\r\n  Broadcast address is 255.255.255.255\r\n  IP MTU 65535 bytes\r\n  Up 24 minutes, 40 seconds\r\nlocalhost(config)#'
```

**It gives me the output of the last device but not the two at the beginning, What could make this exception occur ?**

Answer (score 0):

I got it
The issue was in the list i returned with IPs to ssh on
the list was returned with "\n"

so i have to use `rstrip()"\n"` to get rid of the new line character.